# Color <canvas> based on <area> coordinates

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to fill in polygons when hovering over area elements in a image but I can't figure out how to do the coordinate conversion between the area coordinates and the canvas coordinates.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="width:80%;margin:auto;">
    <img id="MyImg" src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/80000/nahled/3d-shape-icons.jpg" usemap="#Map" style="overflow:hidden;" />
    <canvas id="map_canvas" style="z-index: 10; pointer-events: none;"></canvas>
    <map name="Map" id="MyMap">
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="20,7,12,22,19,49,19,76,13,92,17,110,41,118,67,112,101,118,132,109,131,86,124,61,130,36,132,13,109,4,77,13,58,10,37,2,28,3,15,14" />
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="184,17,181,33,185,52,174,62,165,82,178,95,200,99,208,115,219,126,245,116,254,99,267,98,286,90,289,66,272,53,270,33,271,16,258,8,238,13,234,21,227,19,208,9,193,12" />
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="349,8,333,18,322,44,316,62,327,88,342,111,364,121,402,121,427,106,437,81,442,60,439,40,424,11,395,2,366,2" />
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="501,7,479,34,470,49,472,78,480,103,527,128,577,107,589,48,557,7" />
    </map>
</div>
```

Here's everythin in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/my54g5tq/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your JSFiddle is correct for what you want except for one line.

Change

```
ctx.lineTo(poly[item], h - poly[item + 1]);
```

In

```
ctx.lineTo(poly[item], poly[item + 1]);
```

because the coordinates of 0 are in the top-left corner, not in the bottom-left corner so you don't need to do `height - Y`

**UPDATE:**

you must set a width and height of the canvas statically or programmatically.

Static:

```
<canvas id="map_canvas" style="z-index: 10; pointer-events: none;" width="615" height="457"></canvas>
```

Programmatically (based on image size):

```
var img = document.getElementById("MyImg");
var canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
```

Comment: Good catch! I've updated the fiddle but it seems like only 2 of the 4 shapes are being colored when I change this.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! thank you for your help